# Is there a notation for "Bounded Kleene star"?

Tags: notation, formal-languages

I understand that Kleene star is defined as:

$$V^*=\bigcup_{i = 0 }^\infty V_i = V_0 \cup V_1 \cup V_2 \cup V_3 \cup \ldots.$$

(given $V$ is a formal language, $V_0 = \{\varepsilon\}$, and $V_k$ is a concatenation of V with itself k times, I saw it in some places notated also as $V^k$ so I thought it's worth clarifying)

So if $V = \{a,b,c\}$, then $V^*$ is basically the regex equivalent of `[abc]*`,  meaning "all possible strings containing 'a','b' or 'c' or the empty string **of any length**".

My question is a little naive and coming from Regex. Is there a notation for "all possible strings containing 'a','b' or 'c' or the empty string **up to length $n$**"?

E.g. in regex it would be: `[abc]{0,n}` where `n` is the max length of a word

Is there a an equivalent mathematical notation for this?

e.g. what is the operator on V that means this:

$$V^{\mathrm{something\ like}\{0,n\}?}=\bigcup_{i = 0 }^n V_i = V_0 \cup V_1 \cup \ldots \cup V_n$$

Comment: You could write $V^{\le n}$, perhaps. But you should explain it if you do.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**.

You can find two notations in the literature. The notation $V^{\leqslant n}$, suggested by Zhen Lin and the notation $(1 + V)^n$ (or $(1 \cup V)^n$ if you prefer the union symbol). The latter one does not need to introduce any definition, but the first one is rather intuitive.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on this suggested notation a little, at least to the extent of telling Readers whether you've seen this in practice or are just inventing a notation ?

Comment: @hardmath I apologize, I answered using an ipad and had to struggle to find the math symbols... I expand my answer now...